# Remove Woocommerce Product Short Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the Product Short Description showed on a Single Product Page in Woocommerce. By default it's placed right underneath the price, I want it totally gone.

I tried to use this code: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);` and placed in functions.php of my Child theme folder but it doesn't change anything.

If I try *woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart* or *woocommerce_template_single_meta* to see if the piece of code actually works it removes the add to cart button and product meta but for some reason the excerpt isn't affected.

Any other solutions to remove it?
Thanks!!
Joost

Answer (score 15):

The right snippet is posted here:
[How to remove wordpress Short description tab in single product page in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53720246/10774750)

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

function woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() {
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the code snippet plugin and run

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
   unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );    
   return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Farzy thanks for the help, great plugin, really easy to handle. Code didn't work... Product Short Description still visable.

Comment: Try the woocommerce settings page, there's a tab I'm pretty sure where you can untick them, also your cache might be showing your old site, so delete cache as well.

Comment: Hi @Farzy, unfortunatly no tickbox :( (would be great haha). I check every time in private browser, which doesn't keeps cache.

Comment: WP comes with a plugin that caches the website to everyone, no matter the computer or device's cache. See if you have WP Super Cache or JetPack's settings and see if it caches,  and disable it temporarily.

This worked for me fine when I was removing my reviews and additional info on woo-commerce pages:
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs','woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

    function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );    
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
    return $tabs;

    }

Comment: Hey @Farzy, ok I disabled all caching, but still having difficulties. I've now removed all short description, side wide with an SQL rule: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = 'My bulk change rule' WHERE post_type = 'product'` So everything is gone now, only thing is that Product Short Description is used by Google Product feed to send description to Google services.

Comment: Not too sure what else you can try :(

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it! Not fixed yet unfortunately.