# How to remove wordpress Short description tab in single product page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to remove  Short description tab in single product page in word press?

I have 3 tabs like

1.product description
2.Short description
3.Reviews

I want to remove short description tab if that is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be easier for people to help you if you provide an example of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The short description tab is called `product_summary`; use the snippet below in your `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );

function woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() {
        return;
}
```

Please note that not all the themes are rendering `product_summary` in a tab, for some themes the snippet should be tweaked accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php theme file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset( $tabs['description'] );      

    return $tabs;

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks its working for description tab, not for short description tab,