# PHP Snippet to hide short description when stock is zero in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to implement a PHP Code snippet in my WooCommerce store that will turn off the 'short-description' when the stock of a product is 0. This since in my short description field will then be displayed when the product will be in stock again.

I presume it's a simple if statament checking wether or not the product is in stock and then either show the description or don't.

Unfortunately i'm not familiar with writing PHP snippets for WooCommerce and I haven't been able to find what i'm looking for in the documentation of WooCommerce so far.

Could any of you help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just search a bit! It's no big deal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190295/remove-woocommerce-product-short-description You can now combine this and a stock check (acess `global $product and get stock` to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your functions.php file of your child theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_before_single_product_action' );
function woocommerce_before_single_product_action() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product ) {
        $quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $quantity !== null && $quantity === 0 ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and works.